# pivot longer with dates - R solution

Tags: r, dplyr

apologies for the simple question.

I have database and I want to transform it. Here is the simplified version:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Date_First_test = structure(c(18621, 
17999, 18468), class = "Date"), Date_second_test = structure(c(18622, 
18001, -646272), class = "Date"), Date_third_test = structure(c(18626, 
18016, 18473), class = "Date"), hemoglobin1 = c(100L, 50L, 300L), hemoglobin2 = c(90L, 
60L, 200L), hemoglobin3 = c(80L, 40L, 100L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make a row for each hemoglobin test (I can do this part):

`df %>% pivot_longer(-c(ID, Date_First_test, Date_second_test, Date_third_test), names_to = "test", values_to = "hemoglobin")`

Whilst this part works, I want one date for each test in one column. However, I want to be even more sophisticated and rather than use the date itself, use the relative admission day. That is to say if the first date is day 1, the second date is the day relative to that date etc.

So I want it to look this this:

```
desired_output <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), admission_day = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 6L), 
    hemoglobin = c(100L, 9L, 80L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 300L, 200L, 
    100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

This is where I am completely stuck.

I would value some input. Go easy as I'm a clinician not a bioinformatician!

Comment: There's a mistake in the input for `Date_second_test`: `-646272`

Comment: Thank you, I've spotted that too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pivot_longer` you can reduce this as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = '.value', names_pattern = "(.*?)(?:_|\\d)") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.integer(Date - min(Date) + 1))
```

---

`pivot_longer` part divides the data in 3 columns as :

```
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = '.value', names_pattern = "(.*?)(?:_|\\d)")

#   ID    Date       hemoglobin
#  <chr> <date>          <int>
#1 A     2020-12-25        100
#2 A     2020-12-26         90
#3 A     2020-12-30         80
#4 B     2019-04-13         50
#...
#...
```